# AlertDialog Extern - all fine but not returning the value as I wish

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to make a extern class for AlertDialog. I want to have an *universal* class to use it quickly.
I know the code isn't difficult at all, but there are anyhow many rows to write (or copy) and if I would find a mistake I maybe had to change many code...
I've everything but one thing I don't get.
So it works but returning the correct onClick doesn't work.
I've also tried to make an while loop before returning, but then the app is hanging....
Has somebody any idea?

```
public class RalaAlertDialog{
private static AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;
private static long onClick=RalaInterfaceDefault.FehlerSpezialZahl;

//neutralButton
public static long AlertDialogNeutral(Context class_this, String mssg, String ntrlBttnTxt, boolean dismissable, String title){
    onClick=RalaInterfaceDefault.FehlerSpezialZahl; //default error number
    alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(class_this);
    if(mssg.equals("")){
        mssg="DEFAULT-TEXT";
    }
    if(title.equals("")){
        title="DEFAULT-TITLE";
    }
    if(ntrlBttnTxt.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        System.out.println("No values set - default in use.");
        ntrlBttnTxt="OK";
    }
    alertDialog.setMessage(mssg)
    .setCancelable(dismissable);
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(ntrlBttnTxt,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                    onClick=0;
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
    );

    AlertDialog a=alertDialog.create();
    a.show();
    //wait until button is click before continuing
    return onClick;
}
```

Comment: i guess, in this case, you want it to return 0 but it doesn't...

Comment: yes; and without look it returns my default "error number"...

Comment: your `while` loop will not hang the treatment because the Dialog will be shown but only later. so, in your case, the while will be skiped. print something in your log to understand what i mean. however, when you click the button your onClick becomes 0 but there is nobody to use it.

Comment: oh ok; I understand, but how could I fix it?

Comment: What should I print in my log? I've the code updated now

Comment: i said you could print just to see the code returned.

Comment: ok - In the Main Activity it prints the "Error Number" Just I said, and yes it works so like you said. - Or have I something missunderstood?

Comment: if you are using the value in your MainActivity I guess you can use it like `RalaAlertDialog.onClick`. Also, you could make a public method that returns dialog.isShowing() so you can loop in your main activity...

Comment: the public method doesn't work -> now the main activity frozes; and how do you mean RalaAlertDialog.onClick? its a class witch shows different dialogs from methods (with 1, 2 or 3 buttons)

Comment: sorry. i thought `onClick` is public.

Comment: should I make it public? - I think the method will do the same, doesn' t it?

Comment: what do you want to do if the user presses on the button?

Comment: I don't now until now; I will only have a Class which I could use every time. - "universal"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static AlertDialog getAlertDialog(Context ctx, String title, String message, String posButton, boolean dismissable, final DialogInterface.OnClickListener ocl) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    builder.setTitle(title)
        .setMessage(message)
        .setCancelable(dismissable)
        .setPositiveButton(posButton,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    if(ocl!=null) ocl.onClick(dialog, id);
                }
            });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;
}
```

Use it like this :

```
    AlertDialog dialog = getAlertDialog(this,"Hello","World","OK",false,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.i("DIALOG","OK Clicked");
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
```

Of course you need only one OnClickListener, but I like it better that way.